# How to check if an arbitrary equation is a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, expression-test

I am has some equation, how to check if it is a polynomial(or can be converted to polynomial)?

Example equation: $a+\frac{1}{a}=k$

I know about `PolynomialQ`, but it does not working for this equation:

```
PolynomialQ[a + 1/a - k, a](*False*)
```

The $a+\frac{1}{a}=k$ is eqvivalent to $a^{2}-ak+1=0$

Now, `PolynomialQ` is correct work:

```
PolynomialQ[a^2 - a*k + 1, a](*True*)
```

*Questions:*

1. How to use *Mathematica* for attempt to convert some equation to polynomial form and print result?
2. Similar question for *WolframAlpha*

**Edit:**
I am interested about the general method of checking a certain equation for the possibility of converting to a polynomial, but, it is difficult (or impossible), therefore, assume that the input equation is rational.

Another example, of a polynomial equation([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3592747/how-to-solve-this-equation-that-contains-very-similar-denominators/3593166#3593166)):
$$\frac{a}{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}}+\frac{b}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}}=1$$

```
eq = a/(x + 1/x)^2 + b /(x - 1/x)^2 == 1;
```

Comment: It is unclear to me if you'll always encounter rational functions, or you'll encounter something transcendental that can be made polynomial through a substitution. Nevertheless, for your current example: ``With[{eq = a + 1/a == k}, With[{vars = Reduce`FreeVariables[eq]}, PolynomialQ[First[GroebnerBasis[eq, vars]], vars]]]`` should give the expected answer.

Comment: Would `Numerator[Together[expr]]` give what you want?

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties Important information has been added to the question, please see

Comment: I would then amend Daniel's suggestion to `Numerator[Together[Apply[Subtract, expr]]]`.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
Internal`RationalFunctionQ[a + 1/a - k, a]
(*True*)
```

Comment: This is perfectly fine. Note that now it is exposed publicly as a resource function: `In[9]:= ResourceFunction["RationalFunctionQ"][a + 1/a - k, a]

Out[9]= True`

Answer (score 3):

You essentially want to test whether a given expression is rational in some given variable. The general case is probably going to be subtle, but the naive approach works for your particular example:

```
And @@ {
        PolynomialQ[Numerator[#], a], 
        PolynomialQ[Denominator[#], a]
       } &@ Together[a + 1/a - k]
```

If you want the expanded form, use

```
Expand[# a^Exponent[Denominator[Together[#]], a]] &[a + 1/a - k]
```

Comment: This works for a second example. Obtaining a polynomial form for an equation also interests me, but this code(for getting expanded form) does not work for the second example

Comment: what if you use `Numerator@Together[a/(x + 1/x)^2 + b/(x - 1/x)^2 - 1]`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is undecidable, except for particulars classes of expressions, e. g., rational expressions.